# Nationwide NFL-Team Sports Bar Data?

Tags: data-request, sports

i'm building an nfl-themed app and want to add as many NFL team sports bar locations as possible.

does anyone know of such or list, or even a data-mining strategy  for compiling one?

Comment: What makes a bar a "NFL team sports bar"?

Comment: oh yes...good question...that's a sports bar that caters to fans of one particular NFL team's fanbase in a different city ie http://www.reviewjournal.com/sports/football/nfl-team-bar-directory

Comment: Sounds very unofficial.. maybe there's a wiki or crowdsourced list out there.

Comment: still piecing this together? here's a list of bars in the dmv: https://www.reddit.com/r/washingtondc/wiki/football-bars